# adding OR to an inner join statement

Tags: php, mysql

```
[TABLE1]

 +----------+-------------------+
 | USERNAME | POST              |
 +----------+-------------------+
 | Bob      | 'Hi There'        |
 | Jack     | 'Hello'           |
 | Bob      | 'Today is Monday' |
 +----------+-------------------+

 [TABLE2]

 +----------+-----------+
 | USERNAME | FOLLOWING |
 +----------+-----------+
 | Mike     | Jack      |
 | Jack     | Bob       |
 | Bob      | Jack      |
 | Jack     | Mike      |
 +----------+-----------+
```

I am using this join statement:

```
 SELECT t1.* FROM TABLE1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 
 ON t1.username = t2.following AND t2.username = 'jack';
```

This works, but in addition to returning these results, i also want to add "OR t1.USERNAME = 'jack';

and then another OR.. is there a way to do the join but then also an OR statement

Comment: Pleae consider starting to accept answers to your questions again. You stoped doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify multiple OR conditions inside brackets:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM TABLE1 t1 
     INNER JOIN table2 t2  
         ON t1.username = t2.following 
            AND (t2.username = 'jack' OR t2.username = 'John' OR t2.username = 'Tom');
```

Answer (score 1):

Put that conditions in a `where` clause

```
SELECT t1.* FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.username = t2.following
where t2.username = 'jack'
OR t1.USERNAME = 'jack'
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that like

```
 SELECT t1.* FROM TABLE1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ont1.colName1=t2.Colname2 where colname ='value' or colname='vaue1' or colname='value';
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified method

```
SELECT t1.* FROM TABLE1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.username = t2.following 
where 'jack' in (t1.USERNAME,t2.username)
```